# I installed tsc through apt and now I don't know how to remove or update it

Tags: node.js, linux, typescript, apt

So I was missing typescript on my server and tryed to run tsc and I got the message "don't recognize tsc command, did you mean to install it using apt install tsc?" or something like that. Not really thinking about it, I ran the command. Usually I'd install it using npm i -g typescript. It did install typescript but at the wrong version (2.7.something and i need 4.0+) and runing tsc -v returns the version, but apt-get update doesn't update it, it doesn't turn up on the list when I run dpkg --list, apt-get remove/apt remove tsc/typescript does nothing (can't find package tsc/typescript) but the tsc command does work and attempts to compile my files but throws a bad type error because it's an old version. npm uninstall/remove -g tsc/typescript also does nothing.

How do I remove this tsc and install typescript normally through npm?

EDIT: I should also note, it's not installed locally in some folder. I get the same behaviour anywhere on the server.

Here's a screenshot of some of the commands I tried and the result I got:
[image]

Comment: Try running `apt-get remove tsc` (without `/typescript`).

Comment: i put the slash there to not that I tryed both tsc and typescript, I wasn't actually typing tsc/typescript but apt-get remove tsc AND apt-get remove typescript. I installed the package by typing apt install tsc (if I recall correctly)

Comment: Have you tried running `apt remove tsc` instead of `apt-get remove tsc`?

Comment: Yeah, I attached a screenshot of a bunch of things I tried.

Comment: What is the output of `which tsc` and `npm ls -g tsc`?

Comment: root@personal-server:/var# which tsc

/usr/bin/tsc

root@personal-server:/var# npm ls -g tsc

/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib
└── (empty)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221831/discussion-between-edric-and-supperhero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(Note: Additional information can be found in the [chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221831/discussion-between-edric-and-supperhero))</sub>

TL;DR: It's probably because you've installed the [`node-typescript`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/node-typescript) package via `apt-get` at some point, which only provides `v2.7.2` as the latest version of TypeScript for your current Ubuntu version (which you've specified is 18.04 LTS, or [Bionic Beaver](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver)).

This means that you either have to:

- Switch to a newer version of Ubuntu (e.g. the latest stable, [20.04 - Focal Fossa](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/)) which offers [`v3.8.3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/node-typescript) as the current version, or
- Uninstall the `node-typescript` package (with `sudo apt-get remove node-typescript`) and instead install TypeScript via NPM. This means that TypeScript updates are now decoupled from Ubuntu releases.